# Verification on application of FTC to a multivariable problem - Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Suppose $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $u,v:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable. Prove that the function $F: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by:

$$F(t) = \int_{u(t)}^{v(t)}h(s)ds$$

is differentiable and calculate $F'$.

My question really only revolved around the treatment of $F$ when attempting to show that it is differentiable. In particular my exercises are trying to get me to apply the chain rule in a multivariable environment.

**Attempt**

We can look at $F$ as a function of two variables.

$$F(v(t), u(t)) = \int_{u(t)}^{v(t)}h(s)ds = \int_{c}^{v(t)}h(s)ds - \int_{c}^{u(t)}h(s)ds$$

Where $c$ is a constant.

To show that $F$ is differentiable it suffices to show that the partial derivatives of the function  $F$ are continuous, which means I have to show the following are continuous:

$$DF(v,u) = \bigg[\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} ,\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}\bigg] = \bigg[h(v(t)), -h(u(t)) \bigg]$$

by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

So here is my issue I'm being finicky about. In general by FTC the derivative of a function $F = \int_{c}^{v(t)}h(s)ds$ like the one I have would be:

$$F'(t) = h(v(t))v'(t)$$

But for my derivative $DF$ I treated $v,u$ as variables not dependent on $t$. And when you perform the chain rule on the variable itself obviously you're left with $1$.

Am I allowed to look at the question at this point like this? If I am I would then follow through by pointing out that I have compositions of continuous functions and then that would show the partials of $F$ are continuous.

Mechanically  if I do treat it as such it works out and is in accordance with the solution and what I expected to occur. I'm just a little hesitant on that little part.

Feedback?

Comment: As is mentioned in the other answer, this is a single variable problem.  Once you split it in two, it's just the FTC combined with the chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should mention of course that I find it a little overboard to use multivariable calculus to address this question which can easily be handled using single-variable calculus, but since you asked for it, here's how I'd present it.

---

A function of one-variable obviously is not a function of two variables, and vice-versa: a function of two variables is obviously not a function of one-variable. Seems like a tautological statement. The confusion you're having stems from using the fact that you're using the same letter $F$ twice in different places with different meanings. Whenever you have such doubts, always slow down, and give each and every single function a new name and look at what is being composed with what and how exactly the rules are being applied (and it goes without saying that you should use precise notation, without any "type-errors").

For simplicity of typing, suppose $(a,b)$ is instead replaced by $\Bbb{R}$. We now have several functions in place:

- a continuous $h:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$
- differentiable $u,v:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$
- $F:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $F(t):=\int_{u(t)}^{v(t)}h(s)\,ds$
- $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y):=\int_x^yh(s)\,ds$
- $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $\phi(x):=\int_c^xh(s)\,ds$
- $\gamma:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$ defined as $\gamma(t)=(u(t),v(t))$

I would highly urge you to stick to giving different functions different names, no matter how similar they all seem. Then, from the definitions, we have that

- $f(x,y)=\phi(y)-\phi(x)$. So, $\phi$ being continuously differentiable implies $f$ is continuously differentiable and that $Df_{(x,y)}=
  \begin{pmatrix} -\phi'(x)&\phi'(y)\end{pmatrix}$. In other words, the partial derivatives (using precise notation) are $(\partial_1f)(x,y)=-\phi'(x)$ and $(\partial_2f)(x,y)=\phi'(y)$.
- Differentiability of $u$ and $v$ implies that of $\gamma$. Furthermore, $D\gamma_t=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  u'(t)\\
  v'(t)
  \end{pmatrix}$.
- Finally, $F=f\circ \gamma$. We have already seen that $f$ and $\gamma$ are differentiable, so by the chain rule, their composition is also differentiable, and we have
  \begin{align}
  F'(t)&=Df_{\gamma(t)}\cdot D\gamma_t\\
  &=Df_{(u(t),v(t))}\cdot D\gamma_t\\
  &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  -\phi'(u(t))&\phi'(v(t))
  \end{pmatrix}
  \cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
  u'(t)\\
  v'(t)
  \end{pmatrix}\\
  &=-\phi'(u(t))\cdot u'(t)+\phi'(v(t))\cdot v'(t)
  \end{align}
  Finally, by the FTC, we can replace $\phi'=h$ to get the desired result of
  \begin{align}
  F'(t)&=-h(u(t))\cdot u'(t)+h(v(t))\cdot v'(t).
  \end{align}

Comment: There were a lot more functions that I had to consider than I originally had thought about......definitely will take a step back when thinking of compositions. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: @dc3rd and if you want you can actually breakdown the reasoning for why $f$ is differentiable further. We can define the two projections $\pi_1:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\pi_2:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $\pi_2(x,y)=y$. Then, we have $f=\phi\circ\pi_2-\phi\circ\pi_1$. Now, $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are linear transformations and hence (infinitely) differentiable (this byitself is a very good fact to know). ALso, by FTC $\phi$ is (continuously) differentiable. Thus, we have expressed $f$ as a difference of composites of differentiable functions, hence is differentiable.

Comment: at this stage, it may seem extremely excessive breaking it down to the bolt and nuts of where exactly chain rule can be applied, but trust me being able to recognize this will very much pay off (and for more complicated problems, give simpler solutions).